# ui-sref not working with ng-click (angular-touch) if used without jQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-touch

I have a hard time removing jQuery from our app. The main problem: a simple link combining `ng-click` with `ui-sref`:

```
<a data-ui-sref="main2" data-ng-click="reportClick()">Link</a>
```

The result: `ng-click` fires, `ui-sref` does not.
This only happens when using **angular-touch**, without **jQuery** as a dependency and a mobile browser, or with the emulation of a mobile device in the new chrome 32 (I used an Nexus 4 as emulation target).

A running example: http://jsfiddle.net/scheffield/AEfMm/

To see the effect: http://jsfiddle.net/scheffield/AEfMm/show in a mobile browser

I already did a little research and found out that the event object is broken:

```
element.bind("click", function(e) {
    var button = e.which || e.button;

    if ((button === 0 || button == 1) && !e.ctrlKey && !e.metaKey && !e.shiftKey) {
      // HACK: This is to allow ng-clicks to be processed before the transition is initiated:
      $timeout(function() {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          $state.go(ref.state, params, { relative: base });
        });
      });
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
```

It is an object containing nothing but two functions implemented as `angular.noop`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you managed to figure this out? I am sitting with the same issue.

Comment: Hi, I filed a bug for this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6001